# Custom layout within fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-custom-view

I have a fragment containing a cusom layout and an event listener to handle the user interaction with the custom view. But I get a null pointer exception on setting the event listener inside the fragment. Here, I found that the custom view reference is null in the fragment.

```
public class CustomCalendarView extends LinearLayout {

private EventListener eventListener;
public CustomCalendarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
{
    super(context);
    ............
    cellView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.calendar_grid);
    cellView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if (eventListener == null)
                return false;

            eventListener.onDayLongPress((Date) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i));
            return true;
        }
    });
}

public void setEventListener(EventListener eventListener) {
    this.eventListener = eventListener;
}

public interface EventListener {
    void onDayLongPress(Date date);
}
```

}

```
public class DescribeFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_explore_planner, container, false);
    MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();

    customCalendarView = ((CustomCalendarView) view.findViewById(R.id.calendar_view));
    customCalendarView.setEventListener(new CustomCalendarView.EventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDayLongPress(Date date) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), timeFormatter.format(date), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

}

Comment: Please, provide you code. Code where you setting listener and fetching your view from layout

Comment: You're getting NPE because one of your expressions has a null reference somewhere. Pretty sure that the most anyone can tell without looking at your code!

Comment: maybe cellView has a null reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I hadn't called super(context, attrs) from the constructor of the Custom View. 
Changing super(context) to super(context, attrs) within the constructor having context and attrs as their parameters have resoved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you have error exactly? There are 3 possibilities. First, `customCalendarView` can be null. Check `fragment_explore_planner` has `calendar_view` with id `R.id.calendar_view`. Second, `Date` object that passed as parameter to `EventListener` can be null. Check `adapterView` is null or contains `i` position. And also check `timeFormatter`.

Comment: just found that custmCalendarView is null

Comment: I am glad if i could help you.

Comment: but the other views are not null. I dont know why is this custom view alone null.

Comment: Check `fragment_explore_planner` xml if it contains `calendar_view`

Comment: Yes. it contains calendar_view. I could even get my custom calendar displayed when I remove the customCalender.setEventListener(....)

Comment: finally i got the issue. I had passed super(context) instead of super(context, attrs) in the constructor CustomCalendarView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)